# Why I can directly run a binary file on the Real mode without using linkers?

Tags: assembly, nasm, bootloader, mbr, machine-code

My teacher asked me to write code into MBR of a virtual machine on a virtual box, I firstly use nasm to create a binary file, for instance, like this:

```
nasm my_file.asm -o my_file.bin
```

And I directly use dd command to write into the vhd:

```
dd if=my_file.bin of=machine.vhd bs=512 const=1 conv=notrunc
```

After I boot the virtual machine it did as my expectation.

But what confused me is that we seemingly lose the link process. When we want to get an executable file on computers, we do need a linker to help us do some critical works(like dd something..). But this time we directly use the bin file. So why we can use it in that way?

Comment: Because you are using NASM's BIN file generation which makes NASM skip the linking process and generate all the code and addresses at assembly time itself. You can use NASM to generate ELF objects that can be linked with a linker by using something like `-f elf32` (the default is `-f bin`). `-f elf32` would generate ELF objects that can be linked with a linker like LD

Comment: https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html shows how to use NASM's flat-binary output to manually generate ELF headers to make a tiny Linux ELF executable.  An assembler like NASM can assemble any arbitrary bytes into its output file.

Comment: Technically, the `-f bin` output format of NASM is considered an internal linker that is built into NASM's output format.

Comment: In the good old days just after we stopped punching holes in cards by hand, the assemblers would generate binary files directly.  Thus directives like ORG, so you didnt need a linker.  Some of that legacy is still visible today.

Comment: Also note that manually assembling metadata is exactly what you're doing with `times 510-($-$$) db 0` / `dw 0xAA55` to put the boot signature at the end of the 512-byte MBR; not fundamentally different from using `-fbin` and manually outputting ELF metadata.  It's just a lot simpler :P

Comment: Source for my statement on the built-in `-f bin` linker: https://bugzilla.nasm.us/show_bug.cgi?id=3392655#c2 "`org 7C00h` is a linker directive (just because in the case of bin/ihex/srec formats the linker is built into NASM doesn't change that it is still a linker.)"